# My Professor said versus me and my math

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, solution-verification

I have the following case:

\begin{equation} \int_\limits{0}^1 \int_\limits{0}^1 y\ln(x)dxdy \end{equation}

My professor says that integral should not exist because of the improper integral, my question is why if she is right, we are talking about volume, however, I am just talking about the definite integral?
My answer on wolfram Alpha says the other. [The answer on wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20int%20yln%28x%29%20x%3D0...1%20y%3D0...1) Can Anyone explain? I also know how to do the work to get the answer.

Comment: $log$ is natural logarithmic

Comment: Well the wolfram Alpha calculates the following integral:
$$\int_0^1ydy\int_0^1ln(x)dx=[y^2/2]_0^1[xln(x)-x]_0^1=-\dfrac{1}{2}$$ according to your definition...

Comment: @HungerLearn So am I right the integral exists?

Comment: This is a convergent improper integral, not a Riemann integral. Just like in the one dimension case, these are different things. A Riemann integrable function has to be bounded.

Comment: Well, if you mean, what I have just written, the integral that you say is just a simple integral that you can find in any textbook...do you have some multivariate calculus course?

Comment: The right answer is the one that @Ted Shifrin gave below, what I wrote is the calculation of wolfram Alpha...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a double integral here just adds confusion. The question is: Does the improper single integral 
$$\int_0^1 \ln x\,dx$$
exist? The answer is yes, since
$$\lim_{a\to 0^+} (x\ln x-x)\Big|_a^1  = \lim_{a\to 0^+} (-1 -a\ln a) = -1$$
certainly exists.

If the question is not about *improper* integrals but about whether the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\ln x, & x>0 \\ 0, & x=0\end{cases}$$ is (Riemann) integrable on $[0,1]$, the answer is NO. (Why?)